# Delete vector elements in a vector

Tags: r

I try to do this in R:(for example)
let `x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` and `y=c(1,2,8)`

So

```
x[x!=y] = numeric(0) ????
```

I want to get as a result `3,4,5,6,7`

Is there a practical way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: `setdiff(x,y)` is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value matching `%in%` and remove the elements of `x` that are present in `y`

```
x[-which(x %in% y)]
#[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: This works fine, but only if there is at least one value. This wont return the whole `x` if `y` is null or empty or `c(99,98,97)`, which would somehow be expected.